# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am really a beginner in react and express. I did everything exactly as same as **login**, but in **register** it gives me "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0" this error.

This is my react code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

class Register extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        name: ''
    }
}

onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value})
}

onPasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})
}

onNameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value})
}

onSubmitRegister = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3101/register', {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
    })
    console.log('in')
}

render( props ) {
    return (
        <article className="br3 ba b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-5 center">
            <main className="pa4 black-80">
                <div className="measure">
                    <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                    <legend className="f4 fw6 ph0 mh0">Register</legend>
                    <div className="mt3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlfor="name">Email</label>
                        <input onChange = {this.onEmailChange} className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" type="text" name="name"  id="name" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlfor="name">Name</label>
                        <input onChange = {this.onNameChange} className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" type="email" name="email-address"  id="email-address" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mv3">
                        <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlfor="password">Password</label>
                        <input onChange = {this.onPasswordChange} className="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" type="password" name="password"  id="password" />
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div className="">
                    <input onClick = {this.onSubmitRegister} className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib" type="submit" value="Register" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </article>
    )
}
```

}

export default Register;

This is the server:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const database = {
    users: [
        {
            id: '123',
            name: 'Zihan',
            email: 'zihan@gmail.com',
            password: 'booga',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        },
        {
            id: '124',
            name: 'Shakib',
            email: 'shakib@gmail.com',
            password: 'choto',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
        }
    ]
}

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send(database.users);
}) 

app.post('/signin', (req,res) => {
    if ( req.body.email === database.users[0].email && req.body.password === database.users[0].password ){
        res.json('success');
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).json('error logging in');
    }
})

app.post('/register', (req,res) => {
    const {name, email, password} = req.body;
    database.users.push({
            id: '134',
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
    })

    res.send('registrition sussessful')
})

app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.id === id) {
            found = true;
            return res.send(user);
        } 
    })

    if(!found){
        res.status(404).json('not found')
    }
})

app.put('/image', (req,res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.id === id) {
            found = true;
            user.entries++
            return res.json(user.entries);
        } 
    })

    if(!found){
        res.status(404).json('not found')
    }
})

app.listen(3101, () => {
    console.log('app is runing')
})
```

This is the console tab:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8011.png)

This is the network tab:

[This is response and it seems ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BWsc.png)

As you can see my response is ok and I tested it by postman I am getting the registered user but react is throwing me the error.

Comment: `registration successful` is not a valid JSON response. It should be JSON: `{ message: 'registration successful' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
res.send('registrition sussessful')
```

To this

```
res.json('registrition sussessful')
```

Or even better

```
 res.status(200).send({message: "registration successful" })
```